# Logic app send grid connector not formatting email correctly

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic app which sends an email using the `send grid connector`. The problem is that until yesterday it was sending the email in the right format. And today the line breaks are not working anymore.

So in my code view of this action I have:

```
"body": {
"cc": "test@email.com",
"from": "test2@email2.com",
"subject": "TestEmail",
"text": "ID: @{body('Parse_JSON')?['result']?['simulationId']}\nStatus: @{body('Parse_JSON')?['result']?['status']}\nID: @{body('Parse_JSON')?['result']?['id']}\nPlan: @{body('Parse_JSON')?['plan']}\nName: @{body('Parse_JSON')?['name']}\n\nSeller: @{body('Parse_JSON')?['seller']}\n\nInfo: @{body('Parse_JSON')?['info']}",
"to": "email3@email3.com"},
```

As you can see, after each property on the `text` property theres an `\n` expliciting the line break, it was working before, but now it sends the content as a single line string.

Answer (score 0):

In logic app now, `Send email (V2)` has been **deprecated** which Email body type is **string**.

When you use `Send email (V3)` and `Send email (V4)` connector, both of them Email body type is **html**.

[image]

So, if you line break in Email body, it will show `\n` as in html. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/).

Comment: Hi, any update on this?

I've been trying something similar. As you mentioned "Email body" field is html type, but email body content is always received as plain text, there's no way to handle this. Also, the Send Email (v4) connector from Logic App has a pretty limited editor. Somebody knows about an open issue about this and maybe some other alternatives to do this? 

Thanks in advance.